# I am getting different results while using different compilers

Tags: c++

While trying out a question related to armstrong number i am getting different answers in VS-Code and Programiz online compiler https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/online-compiler/ ..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std ; 

int main(){

int number ; 
cin >> number ; 

int sum = 0; 
int original = number;
 

while (number > 0)
{
    int element ; 
    element = number%10 ; 

    sum = sum + pow(element,3) ; 
    number = number/10 ; 
}
cout << sum << endl ; 
cout << number << endl ; 
cout << original << endl ; 


if (sum == original)
{
    cout << "It is an Armstrong number " << endl ; 
}
else cout << "It is not an Armstrong number " << endl ; 


}
```

[image: This is the output on Vs code]

This was the output on vs code .

[image: This is the output from Programiz ..]

This was the output on programiz compiler ...

Pls do enlighten as to why is this happening and how can this be corrected ..

Comment: One of the reasons why this could be happening is that any call to `pow()` that supplies two integer values is fundamentally broken. You might be surprised to learn that `pow(10, 3)`, for example, may not exactly be 1000.

Comment: ... so write a simple function to multiply in a loop.

Comment: `pow(element, 3);` that's your problem right there.  Change it to `element*element*element`.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own integer power function e.g.
(the constexpr allows the static_assert tests at compile time)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

static constexpr unsigned int int_pow(unsigned int value, unsigned int power)
{
    int result{ 1 };

    for (int i = power; i > 0; --i)
    {
        result *= value;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(int_pow(10, 3) == 1000);
    static_assert(int_pow(2, 3) == 8);

    return 0;
}
```